# Restricting text with 22units and 3 decimal points

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How can I restrict input to a text box so that it accepts only 22 units and 3 decimal points only?

Comment: And what you have done?

Comment: function ValidateDecimalInputs(e) {

 

    var beforeDecimal =22;
    var afterDecimal = 3;
   
    $('#'+e.id).on('input', function () {
        this.value = this.value
          .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')            
          .replace(new RegExp("(^[\\d]{" + beforeDecimal + "})[\\d]", "g"), '$1') 
          .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         
          .replace(new RegExp("(\\.[\\d]{" + afterDecimal + "}).", "g"), '$1');   
    });
    }

Comment: this is what i have done @शेखर

Answer (score 0):

And take a look at this , only numbers and comma .

When leaving to another textbox it removes more then 22 and when there is more then  1 comma it removes and returns the numbers to 3 numbers behind the comma.

This is more then 22 and more then 1 comma **1234,56789,123,45699999**

Leaving the Textbox to a button or other Textbox it wil return this **1234567891234569,999**

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim a_chars As String = "0123456789,", t_tekst As String, i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(TextBox1.Text)
        If InStr(a_chars, Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Only numbers and comma")
        Else
            t_tekst = t_tekst & Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = t_tekst
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = i
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating

    If TextBox1.TextLength > 22 Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 22)
        MsgBox("More then 22 .")
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
    Dim t_tekst As String, d_sep As Boolean, c_placed As Boolean, lgt As Integer

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

    d_sep = False
    lgt = Len(TextBox1.Text)
    t_tekst = vbNullString

    For i As Integer = 1 To lgt
        Select Case Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)
            Case ".", ","
                d_sep = True
            Case Else
                If i >= lgt - 2 Then
                    If d_sep And Not c_placed Then
                        t_tekst = t_tekst & ","
                        c_placed = True
                    End If
                End If
                t_tekst = t_tekst & Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = t_tekst

End Sub
```

Comment: You can adjust it like they only can type 22 in the Textbox , but this is only an example